# Can the druid cantrip Thorn Whip really defeat a water weird this easily?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, druid, cantrips, forced-movement

[Water weirds](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/water-weird) (MM, p. 299) have the Water Bound trait:

> The water weird dies if it leaves the water to which it is bound or if that water is destroyed.

If a water weird is fewer than 10 feet from the edge of its pool—which it would be if it were trying to Constrict and grapple characters who are on solid ground—can a druid cast [*thorn whip*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/thorn-whip) to pull it from its pool, killing it instantly? I believe the druid can, but am I missing something?

Comment: Relevant meta: [Stance on using D&D Beyond for references?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7669/stance-on-using-dd-beyond-for-references). Ideally, you might want to edit the page number from the book, and the relevant quote from the statblock, to explain your logic - that way it's accessible regardless of format (book or digital) and the relevant information is retained even if the original is changed/moved.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Yes.

The rules do not indicate that the *thorn whip* spell uses a grapple (which the weird would be immune to).  The water weird has no immunity to the effect of *thorn whip*.  Very clever use of a spell to defeat a creature.

Comment: Having used thorn whip as a player to one-shot more than one enemy, I can attest that it is occasionally *incredibly* game breaking. As a DM I'd narrate this as a bizarre spell interaction (the thorn whip 'drinking up' the weird and leaving an unexpected mass of thorny vines, probably), rather than some form of odd grapple-but-not-a-grapple dragging the weird out of the pool.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Maybe the thorn whip spell solidifies / jellyfies the weird enough to make it grapplable?